# Submitting a block to the .org repo: do I submit compiled code, or source code?

Tags: block-editor, svn, plugin-repository

I plan on submitting a Gutenberg block to the repo.

What am I supposed to submit? Only the compiled code is distributed. Based on how the SVN repo works, it seams I should NOT be submitting the source code.

Comment: I don't see anything about not submitting source code: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/add-your-plugin-to-the-block-directory/ What about SVN makes you think you shouldn't submit source code?

Comment: Only the .org plugin review team can truly answer this, ask them over on the .org forums or their Slack channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-to-use-subversion/). And you're right, put the code to distribute there. I'm quoting the handbook:

> SVN and the Plugin Directory are a release repository. Unlike Git, you
> shouldn’t commit every small change, as doing so can degrade
> performance. Please only push finished changes to your SVN repository.

Comment: This isn't saying anything about source code.

Comment: His question though was if he should submit source code OR compiled code. I think the issue here is that SVN is for distributing, not for developing.